# Deleted Ubuntu, now I can't access Windows

Tags: multi-boot, grub, gnu

My laptop was working on dual-boot, I had Ubuntu Mate and Windows 8. I wanted to delete Ubuntu, so I did it through Windows Disk Management by deleting the partition where Linux was. That way I deleted GRUB boot, and I inserted the USB drive with System Repair on it, but after restarting the System Repair won't run. Tried a few commands I searched online, but nothing works, I only get 'you need to load the kernel first.'. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Is your BIOS set to boot from USB first?  Try disconnecting the hard drive to verify it is actually trying to boot from the USB drive.  Although I think the answer below as an overall concept should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You deleted Ubuntu partition => you deleted second stage of GRUB.

First stage of GRUB is still in control of the booting as it occupies the MBR (Master Boot Record) I suppose (let's ignore UEFI for this solution to simplify things).

To fix Windows 8 boot you need to execute two commands when booted from Windows 8 installation/recovery USB: (on command prompt)

1. `bootsect /nt60 ALL /mbr`

bootsect writes boot code only to "usual" Windows partitions (e.g. NTFS, FAT) and MBR, does not write boot code to Linux partitions (not relevant in this case).

2. `bcdboot N:\windows /s c:`

assuming c: is active partition, N: is where Windows is installed.

You can use diskpart.exe to get info about **active partition on hard disk** with:

```
list disk

select disk #num   - (#num = number of hard disk)

list vol
```

you get a list of volumes - volume (with or without drive letter) with "System" in last column is active.

You can map a volume like this:

```
sel vol #num   - (#num = number of active)

assign LETTER=R
```

assigns drive letter R: to active.